# Внешний вид context menu

Tags: android, android-menu, android-context-menu

Воспроизвожу шаги по туториалу https://o7planning.org/ru/12615/android-contextmenu-tutorial
Вернее буквальный копипаст. Разве что у меня API 23.  Android Studio 4.0.1

И в результате вместо ожидаемого (как у них)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

получается меню в "старом стиле"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так? И что делать?

ps: Давать ссылку куда-то не очень хорошо, но я не вижу смысла копипастить типичный базовый код для создания меню. У меня нет проблем с созданием меню. У меня проблема его внешнего вида несмотря на androidX, appcompat, более высокий API level и так далее.

Comment: Что бы уточнить, вы используете androidX? и не понял насчет API 23. Android Studio 4.0.1 вам нужен минимальный API 23(Андроид 6.0) или API 14(Андроид 4.0)??

Comment: @Tiarait в туториале при создании проекта minimumsdk=16, а я выбрал 23. В остальном я полностью копирую код из туториала. А там в именах androidx.

Comment: странно, повторил у себя код из туториала и результат как у них. Трудно что либо предположить, если тему не меняли то возможно дело в устройстве. Как альтернативу посмотрите PopupMenu

Comment: @Tiarait если результат нужный, то выложите куда-нибудь проект, а я открою у себя и все станет ясно.

Comment: https://github.com/Tiarait/TestContextMenu

Comment: @Tiarait ну с попапменю все ясно. а в остальном по лонгклику то же старое меню. Попробовал на эмуляторах с api 17,19,23 - старый вид , api 27 - новый вид меню (какой и ожидается). А значит либо их косяк когда делали скрин, то потом выбрали версию выше или же дело в чем то другом, что я и хочу выяснить.

Comment: да в API 24 поменяли ContextMenu, а в туториале для скрина использовали эмулятор с API 24+, хотя подробной документации про смену ContextMenu не нашел. Здесь немного другая проблема но смысл тот же https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40867621/contextmenu-position-is-messed-up-in-android-7

Comment: @Tiarait Похоже на то, хотя я тоже не нашел про смену внешнего вида, разве что в api24 можно задать contextPopupMenuStyle, что указывает на новый вид меню в 24. Оформляйте как ответ и я его приму.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В API 24 поменяли вид ContextMenu, а в туториале для скрина использовали эмулятор с API 24+, хотя подробной документации про смену ContextMenu не нашел. В том же Api 24 [существует проблема с отображением](https://www.mysysadmintips.com/other/programming/758-listview-pop-up-context-menu-broken-in-android-7-api-24)

Так же в API 24 были добавлены ряд функций для класса View, например `public boolean showContextMenu(float x, float y)` которая и отвечает за вызов нового ContextMenu

Если важен одинаковый стиль то можно программно вызывать старый метод

```
button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            button.showContextMenu();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

[источник из stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49237694/7540461)

*тема мне показалась интересной, если еще что найду - дополню*